# File drag and drop functionality in Angular js/MVC not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, drag-and-drop, angular-file-upload

I am trying to implement a simple file drag and drop functionality in Angular js/MVC.

I created a directive for the drag and drop.

```js
(function (angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('fileupload', [])
     .directive("myDirective", function ($parse) {
         return {
             restrict: 'A',
             link: fileDropzoneLink
         };
         function fileDropzoneLink(scope, element, attrs) {
             element.bind('dragover', processDragOverOrEnter);
             element.bind('dragenter', processDragOverOrEnter);
             element.bind('dragend', endDragOver);
             element.bind('dragleave', endDragOver);
             element.bind('drop', dropHandler);

             var onImageDrop = $parse(attrs.onImageDrop);

             //When a file is dropped
             var loadFile = function (files) {
                 scope.uploadedFiles = files;
                 scope.$apply(onImageDrop(scope));
             };

             function dropHandler(angularEvent) {
                 var event = angularEvent.originalEvent || angularEvent;
                 var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
                 event.preventDefault();
                 loadFile(files)
             }

             function processDragOverOrEnter(angularEvent) {
                 var event = angularEvent.originalEvent || angularEvent;
                 if (event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                 }
                 event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
                 element.addClass('dragging');
                 return false;
             }

             function endDragOver() {
                 element.removeClass('dragging');
             }
         }
     });
}(angular));
```

**This is the template**

```html
<div class="dropzone" data-my-Directive on-image-drop="$ctrl.fileDropped()">
Drag and drop pdf files here
</div>
```

**This is my component code**

```js
(function (angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('test', [])
        .component('contactUs', contactUs());

    function contactUs() {
        ContactUs.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
        function ContactUs($scope, $http) {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.files = [];
         
            ctrl.services = {
                $scope: $scope,
                $http: $http,
            };
        }

        //file dropped
        ContactUs.prototype.fileDropped = function () {
            var ctrl = this;
            var files = ctrl.services.$scope.uploadedFiles;
            angular.forEach(files, function (file, key) {
                ctrl.files.push(file);
            });
        }


        return {
            controller: ContactUs,
            templateUrl: 'partials/home/contactus/'
        };
    }
}(angular));
```

Sometimes the drag and drop works absolutely fine without any issue. But some times I get the below issue and the drag and drop does not work and I get the black invalid cursor.

[image]

This issue is random and i do not see any errors in the console.

And I also tried other third party components like angular-file-upload
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload and I am seeing the exact same issue with that component also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT :***

Answer updated for pdf preview. The code is available in the same plunker.

References : Excellent solution by @Michael at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21732039/6347317

In the example above, the response from the http POST is used in "new Blob([response]". In angular-file-upload library, the "response" would be "fileItem._file" property in "uploader.onAfterAddingFile" function. You can console log to check the data these have , so as to understand it better.

Also please note that if PDf viewer is not enabled in chrome, it has to be enabled using this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en

***END EDIT***

Since you mentioned that you tried with angular-file-upload library, i have created a plunker with it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jeYg5fIRaC9wuEYSNOux?p=info

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-file-upload/2.5.0/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">

                        <h3>Select files</h3>

                        <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                            <!-- 3. nv-file-over uploader="link" over-class="className" -->
                          <div class="well my-drop-zone" style="width:300px" nv-file-drop nv-file-over="" uploader="uploader" 
                          filters="syncFilter">
                               <label>
                              Click here or Drag and Drop file
                                 <input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" nv-file-select nv-file-over="" uploader="uploader" 
                                 filters="syncFilter" multiple/>
                                </label> 
                                  <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': uploader.queue[0].progress + '%' }"></div>
                                  </div>
                                <div>{{uploader.queue[0].file.name}}</div>

                                  <div ng-show="showAlert" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
                                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                                     <strong>Clear the existing file before uploading again!!</strong> 
                                  </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>

      </body>

    </html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularFileUpload']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,FileUploader) {
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader();

        // FILTERS

        // a sync filter
        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'syncFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                console.log('syncFilter' + this.queue.length);
                return this.queue.length < 1;
            }
        });

        // an async filter
        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'asyncFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options, deferred) {
                console.log('asyncFilter');
                setTimeout(deferred.resolve, 1e3);
            }
        });


uploader.allowNewFiles = true;
uploader.filters.push({
  name:'csvfilter',
  fn: function() {
    return this.allowNewFiles;
}
});

        // CALLBACKS

        uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
            console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
            $scope.showAlert=true;
        };


        uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {

  };
});
```

It is pretty straight forward and i dont get the error you mentioned. We are actually using this library in one of our Projects. I have also added a filter to restrict upload to only 1 file.

Please check this and let me know how it goes or if you have any doubts in the code.

Comment: thanks vijay but i am still seeing the same issue, i noticed that when i try running the code in the plain html file and running without the visualstudio/iis the files are being dropped on the web page and it works  but when i run the same code in visual studio/iis i am seeing the above wierd issue

Comment: Oh ok. Then it could be some setup in Visula studio.How are you opening the web page in Visual Studio? Saw this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226600/visual-studio-does-not-let-me-drag-drop-items-into-it

Comment: Not sure if this is it but can you please look at the Solution at the bottom of the post.  Might just be Visual Studio being Visual Studio:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T520060/dxfileuploader-drag-and-drop-is-not-working-in-ie11-when-running-a-web-project-in-visual

Comment: I havent used Visual Studio as an IDE. I mostly use Sublime Text . Since you suspect its a Visual Studio issue, do you have the option to switch your IDE to something else? If yes, please do. Otherwise, I am afraid I dont have any more suggestions, since the code as such is working fine.

Comment: hi vijay  so finally we decide to use angular file upload . but we also want to implement the pdf preview functionality , can you please advise how do we implement this? any information will be helpfull

Comment: I have updated my answer for pdf preview and updated the plunker as well. Please check if it works for you.